# positive functional on Banach *-algebra (with appro. identity) is continuous?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

**Theorem** (N. Th.Varopoulos): Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a Banach *-algebra
with a bounded approximate identity. Then every positive functional $T$ on $\mathcal{B}$ is continuous.

I think this theorem is proved in as an application of [Cohen  factorisation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Hewitt_factorization_theorem): in ''N. Th. Varopoulos, Sur les formes positives d'une algébre de Banach, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 258 (1964) 2465-2467.''

> Question: I'm looking for the proof of the above theorem and some further progress (some generalisation   of the above theorem),  possibly rewritten in English (I guess). Can you sketch the proof (key ideas) or specific reference?

Answer (score 4):

F. F. Bonsall & J. Duncan, Complete Normed Algebras, Springer 1973: §37, Star Representations and Positive Functionals, Theorem 15 (p. 201).

> Let $A$ (a Banach star algebra) have a bounded two-sided approximate identity, then every positive linear functional on $A$ is continuous

I'm not sure if your functionals are implicitly linear, if not then this is a weaker statement of course (but the proof seems short).